# How to display random id values using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to display textbox values. i have a for loop values, need to display that loop vales in textbox my codes are following:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function saveedit(id)
{  
var str = 'txt'+id;
str = str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
var quote_send_id=document.getElementById(str).value;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
for(i=0;i<=5;i++)
{
?>
<input type="text" name="txt" id="txt<?php echo $i; ?>" value="">
<?php
}
?>
<?php
for(i=0;i<=5;i++)
{
?>
<input type="button" name="txt" onclick="editfun(<?php echo $i; ?>);" value="">
<?php
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the problem? or error?

Comment: if you just want a randon number check this function http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.rand.php

Comment: cannot read property 'value' of null

Comment: when do you call the function saveedit and what is the parameter value?

Comment: your id is "txt+id" and in the JS function you try to find "item_product_name+id"

Comment: try to replace in the JS function `var str = 'item_product_name'+id;`by `var str = 'txt'+id;` and call `saveedit(0)` for example

Comment: oh thanks @cmnardi i changed, but it showing same error

Comment: why your PHP variables are without '$'?  `for(i=0;i<=5;i++)`

Comment: If you click button with ID 1 you want to display value as txt1,If you click button with ID 2 you want to display value as txt2... Am i right?

Answer (score 0):

Your function name is wrong in the button

`function saveedit(id) {
    var str = 'txt'+id;
    str = str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
    var quote_send_id=document.getElementById(str).value
    console.info(quote_send_id);
}`

`<?php for($i=0;$i<=5;$i++) { ?>
<input type="text" name="txt" id="txt<?php echo $i; ?>" value="">
<br/>
<?php }`

`<?php for($i=0;$i<=5;$i++) { ?>
<input type="button" name="txt" onclick="saveedit(<?php echo $i; ?>);" value="">
<br>
<?php } ?>`